# Android View Binding onClickListener not being called

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I'm updating an app and I read that the recommended way to handle Views now is to use View Binding. I followed [the instructions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), however I'm having some problems:

Adding a click listener with the following works:

```
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_login)).setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Log.v(TAG, "findViewById press");
});
```

Whereas the following doesn't

```
binding.btn_login.setOnClickListener(v -> {
   Log.v(TAG, "View Binding press");
});
```

The docs [say it should](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities). I wanted to try this on a new project, to ensure it wasn't related to the app configuration in some way, but I get the same result - it doesn't work.

I'm initializing it like so:

```
public class Login extends BaseClassFragmentActivity {
    ActivityLoginBinding binding;
    private final String TAG = "[LOGIN]";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it seems ok. 
Add the initialization of `binding` and `setContentView` to your question.

Comment: @HamidSj Thanks for the feedback. Just edited and yeah, it seems I need to `setContentView(binding.getRoot())`. Why is that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider that you should use `setContentView(binding.getRoot());` in your `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @HamidSj's comment, I noticed I wasn't calling `setContentView(binding.getRoot())`, but instead `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)`.

Using `binding.getRoot()` fixed the issue, but I'm not sure why

Comment: I'm glad that your problem solved. can you accept my answer please?

Answer (score 2):

Initialising binding after setting `setContentView` will prevent binding initialisation and views binding correctly.

You need to initialise binding first and then setting content view
with: `setContentView(binding.getRoot())`.

Answer (score 1):

Call setContentView after inflating.

```
public class Login extends BaseClassFragmentActivity {
        ActivityLoginBinding binding;
        private final String TAG = "[LOGIN]";
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    
            binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            View view = binding.getRoot();
            setContentView(view);
        }
    }
```

As you are using id `btn_login`, use `setOnClickListener` as

```
binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "View Binding press");
                }
            });
```